# How to call a script in a subdirectory from Perl using system (Windows)

Tags: windows, perl, directory, path, relative-path

I have a base directory, call it MAIN and two subfolders, SCRIPTS and WORK.
When using the following line of code, the script calls upon the job and runs it, only if  job_name is in the MAIN folder, then prints output or error to job_name.out/.err in the WORK folder.

```
system("$job_name > ./WORK/$job_name.out 2> ./WORK/$job_name.err");
```

If I move the jobs into SCRIPTS then I cannot seem to find an efficient/simple way to call upon it.. I figured something similar to the following code would work:

```
system("SCRIPTS/$job_name > ./WORK/$job_name.out 2> ./WORK/$job_name.err");
```

But I get errors like:

- `SCRIPTS is not recognized as an internal or external command......`
- `The system cannot find the path specified.`

How can I compose this command to get it to work from a subdirectory?

Comment: Where do you execute your script from in the second case? Your `MAIN` folder ? is writting `./SCRIPTS/$job_name` changing anything ?

Comment: "But I cannot get it to work!" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: Sorry ikegami, the errors I received varied depending on the syntax I was using, I was getting errors from "SCRIPTS is not recognized as an internal or external command......" to "The system cannot find the path specified." I will be sure to be more specific in future questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, filepaths are specified with backslashes (`\`).

Instead of `system("SCRIPTS/$job_name"...)`, try `system("SCRIPTS\\$job_name"...)`

Comment: I thought about that as well, but then how could his 1st example have worked ?

Comment: @Ploutox : Windows is more picky about the path to the command being run than that of the output redirection. Try it out with `C:\> echo "Hi" > ./some_subdir/test.txt`

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't think you could have an hybrid syntax like that. I'm more of a Linux person myself ...

Comment: @Ploutox : Windows is quite quirky. I think the `/` came into the picture with Windows NT 4.0 when they implemented/copied a lot of Unix's functionality (pipes, etc.)